# Sirikit for Apple tv

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, sirikit

I want to know if Apple has yet released siri kit for Apple tvos for developers? I could not find any link for Sirikit for tvOS. If yes, Please share the link where I can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment SiriKit only available for iOS 10. the `Intents` framework is only available on iOS 10.0+ and macOS 10.12+